# javascript style change onclick not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick, styles

I have two divs containing the Facebook Like Box and the Twitter Profile Widget separately. I have made two buttons or "tabs" which, when clicked, will move both itself and its respective div to the right and into the screen (the div containing the widget and like box is hidden outside of the browser window using positioning).

When I click the first button, it works fine. But when I click the second button, only the div moves, but the button stays. Using z-indexing, I was able to put the tab on top of the div. When I clicked the button again, the button moved out - but the div moved back in.

The code for the two divs is exactly the same, except for image names and id's (naturally).

Here is the javascript contained in the -section:

```
function facebookToggle1() {
var fb = $('#facebooktab'); // save reference to element
if( fb.css('margin-left') === '-250px' ) {
    fb.css('margin-left', '0px');
    fb.css('margin-top', '-150px');
    fb.css('z-index', '2');
} else {
    fb.css('margin-left', '-250px');
    fb.css('margin-top', '-300px');
    fb.css('z-index', '0');
}
}

 function facebookToggle2() {
var fb2 = $('#facebooktoggle');
if( fb2.css('margin-left') === '0px' ) {
    fb2.css('margin-left', '250px');
} else {
    fb2.css('margin-left', '0px');
}
}

function twitterToggle1() {
var twi = $('#twittertab'); // save reference to element
if( twi.css('margin-left') === '-250px' ) {
    twi.css('margin-left', '0px');
    twi.css('margin-top', '-150px');
    twi.css('z-index', '2');
} else {
    twi.css('margin-left', '-250px');
    twi.css('margin-top', '-300px');
    twi.css('z-index', '0');
}
}

function twitterToggle2() {
var twi2 = $('#twittertoggle');
if( twi2.css('margin-left') === '0px' ) {
    twi2.css('margin-left', '250px');
} else {
    twi2.css('margin-left', '0px');
}
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
div id="facebooktab"> <!-- Contains facebook feed in static div on the left side of the screen -->
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Torucon /115138348575729" data-width="250" data-height="300" data-show-faces="false" data-border- color="white" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
</div>
<div id="facebooktoggle" onclick="facebookToggle1(); facebookToggle2();"> <!--Visible, click-able switch to show/hide the facebook feed -->
</div>
<div id="twittertab"> <!-- Contains twitter feed in static div on the left side of the screen -->
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
version: 2,
type: 'profile',
rpp: 4,
interval: 30000,
width: 250,
height: 300,
theme: {
shell: {
  background: '#51c3e2',
  color: '#ffffff'
},
tweets: {
  background: '#ffffff',
  color: '#000000',
  links: '#ff0000'
 }
},
features: {
scrollbar: true,
loop: false,
live: true,
behavior: 'all'
}
}).render().setUser('ToruconOfficial').start();
</script>
</div>
<div id="twittertoggle" onclick="twitterToggle1(); twitterToggle2();"> <!-- Visible click-able switch to show/hide the twitter feed -->
</div>
```

I'm sorry if the code looks messy - it looks cleaner with some lines between the divs!
If you wish, the code is seen in action at http://www.torucon.no/no/

(In case of stupid - for people like myself - remember to view the page with IE to see my problem!)

Thank you so very much for all help!

Comment: even due i do not offer a solution to your problem, please see the following code i have composed for you: http://jsfiddle.net/pzn6t/6/
it is "the right way" to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The two CSS files have different z-index values for #twittertoggle:

torucon.css has z-index: 1
torucon_ie.css has z-index: 2

Changing the torucon_ie.css to z-index: 1 fixes the issue in IE.

Comment: It certainly makes the tab hide under the div - but the point is that the tab should be moved to the right along with the twitter widget.
The javascript is made so it would move everything back if clicked again, so it is important that the button is positioned in a way so that it is accessible :)